# how to give proper snap permission to shutter on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor, snap, shutter

After trying to upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 my screenshot program shutter doesnt work anymore.

Steps to reproduce:

- start shutter
- choose rectangular area

result:
all the screen turns black with some grey pixels.

stdout:

```
...
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.301" (uid=1000 pid=797753 comm="/usr/bin/perl /snap/shutter/27/bin/shutter " label="snap.shutter.shutter (enforce)") interface="org.gnome.GConf.Server" member="GetDefaultDatabase" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.gnome.GConf" (uid=1000 pid=713079 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2 " label="unconfined")
...
```

So is it a missing AppArmor permission?
What is missing?
Can anybody help?

Environment:

- shutter 0.94.3 aus Alan Pope (popey) installiert
- VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
- Linux  5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I propose to install the latest Shutter version (currently 0.99.2) from the official repositories as the snap version is heavily outdated.

Version 0.99.2 can take full screen screenshots in Wayland, but other modes are not yet supported. If you want to use the full functionality, you would have to switch to Xorg: https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/issues/187

Comment: I didn't know `shutter` was officially supported anymore.  I had to use the snap version in ubuntu 20 because it was no longer available.  This is good news!